# set Theme using plugin in Chartjs 3.9.1

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to set theme using plugin in New version of chartjs 3.9.1, i'm trying to add "chartjs-plugin-colorschemes" plugin, link is: https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/.

In old version of chartjs v2.9.3 is working fine with this plugin.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="chartMenu">
        <p>WWW.CHARTJS3.COM (Chart JS 3.9.1)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
        <div class="chartBox" style="width: 500px">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/0.4.0/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes.min.js">

        </script>

    <script>

        const data = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [1, 2, 3].map(function (i) {
                return {
                    label: 'Dataset ' + i,
                    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].map(Math.random),
                    fill: false
                }
            })
        };


        const config = {
            type: 'line',
            data,
            options: {
                plugins: [
                    {
                        "colorschemes": {
                            scheme: 'brewer.RdYlBu3',
                        }
                    }]
            },
        };

        const myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code that I tried, can someone please guide me what i missed.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It was never correctly updated for V3 so the only thing you can try is if the export they do also works for CDN version of distribution and try to register it. Otherwise you will need to wait until or if the plugin ever gets updated to work with V3 and above:

This might work if CDN version supports it, otherwise you are out of luck and need to stay with V2 or implement the plugin and coloring yourself:

```js
Chart.register(ColorSchemesPlugin);

const data = {};
const config = {};

new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

The demo site uses chart.js v2.8.0. As you can see on [this page](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#plugins), the plugin you try to use doesn't work for chart.js v3 and later.

You probably can take a look at [this pluging](https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-autocolors) and adapt it to your need to generate the colors you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some work around,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Getting Started with Chart JS with www.chartjs3.com</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="chartMenu">
    <p>WWW.CHARTJS3.COM (Chart JS 3.9.1)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chartCard">
    <div class="chartBox">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-UXumZrZNiOwnTcZSHLOfcTs0aos2MzBWHXOHOuB0J/R44QB0dwY5JgfbvljXcklVf65Gc4El6RjZ+lnwd2az2g=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/1.2.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-klQv6lz2YR+MecyFYMFRuU2eAl8IPRo6zHnsc9n142TJuJHS8CG0ix4Oq9na9ceeg1u5EkBfZsFcV3U7J51iew=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


  <script>
    const dt = [];
    const labels = [];
    for (let index = 1; index < 20; index++) {
      labels.push("Label_" + index);
      dt.push(index);
    }

   var ThemeDictionary = {

      Classic10: ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf"],
        ClassicMedium10: ["#729ece", "#ff9e4a", "#67bf5c", "#ed665d", "#ad8bc9", "#a8786e", "#ed97ca", "#a2a2a2", "#cdcc5d", "#6dccda"],
        ClassicLight10: ["#aec7e8", "#ffbb78", "#98df8a", "#ff9896", "#c5b0d5", "#c49c94", "#f7b6d2", "#c7c7c7", "#dbdb8d", "#9edae5"],
        Classic20: ["#1f77b4", "#aec7e8", "#ff7f0e", "#ffbb78", "#2ca02c", "#98df8a", "#d62728", "#ff9896", "#9467bd", "#c5b0d5", "#8c564b", "#c49c94", "#e377c2", "#f7b6d2", "#7f7f7f", "#c7c7c7", "#bcbd22", "#dbdb8d", "#17becf", "#9edae5"],
        ClassicGray5: ["#60636a", "#a5acaf", "#414451", "#8f8782", "#cfcfcf"],
        ClassicColorBlind10: ["#006ba4", "#ff800e", "#ababab", "#595959", "#5f9ed1", "#c85200", "#898989", "#a2c8ec", "#ffbc79", "#cfcfcf"],
        ClassicTrafficLight9: ["#b10318", "#dba13a", "#309343", "#d82526", "#ffc156", "#69b764", "#f26c64", "#ffdd71", "#9fcd99"],
        ClassicPurpleGray6: ["#7b66d2", "#dc5fbd", "#94917b", "#995688", "#d098ee", "#d7d5c5"],
        ClassicPurpleGray12: ["#7b66d2", "#a699e8", "#dc5fbd", "#ffc0da", "#5f5a41", "#b4b19b", "#995688", "#d898ba", "#ab6ad5", "#d098ee", "#8b7c6e", "#dbd4c5"],
        ClassicGreenOrange6: ["#32a251", "#ff7f0f", "#3cb7cc", "#ffd94a", "#39737c", "#b85a0d"],
        ClassicGreenOrange12: ["#32a251", "#acd98d", "#ff7f0f", "#ffb977", "#3cb7cc", "#98d9e4", "#b85a0d", "#ffd94a", "#39737c", "#86b4a9", "#82853b", "#ccc94d"],
        ClassicBlueRed6: ["#2c69b0", "#f02720", "#ac613c", "#6ba3d6", "#ea6b73", "#e9c39b"],
        ClassicBlueRed12: ["#2c69b0", "#b5c8e2", "#f02720", "#ffb6b0", "#ac613c", "#e9c39b", "#6ba3d6", "#b5dffd", "#ac8763", "#ddc9b4", "#bd0a36", "#f4737a"],
        ClassicCyclic13: ["#1f83b4", "#12a2a8", "#2ca030", "#78a641", "#bcbd22", "#ffbf50", "#ffaa0e", "#ff7f0e", "#d63a3a", "#c7519c", "#ba43b4", "#8a60b0", "#6f63bb"],
    }

    var Theme = "Classic10"

    // setup 
    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: dt,
        backgroundColor: ThemeDictionary[Theme],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          zoom: {
            zoom: {
              wheel: {
                enabled: true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can create you own theme colors and add into "ThemeDictionary" dictionary with key and set your key into "Theme" variable, that's it.

Please suggest if anything I missed.

Comment: follow this link if you want to set theme per series base 
https://jsfiddle.net/1n9r8smy/1/

Answer (score 0):

In chart js v3, i had to use this library to theme the charts.

```
"chart.js": "^3.0.2",
"chartjs-plugin-colorschemes-v3": "0.5.4",
```

registered in the chart options.

```
import ColorSchemesPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes-v3';
import { Classic10, Tableau10, ClassicLight10 } from 'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes-v3/src/colorschemes/colorschemes.tableau';
import { SetThree12, SetTwo8, SetOne9, Accent8 } from 'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes-v3/src/colorschemes/colorschemes.brewer';

const config = {
  plugins: [ColorSchemesPlugin],
  options: {
    plugins: {
            colorschemes: {
                override: true,
                scheme: Classic10,
            },
            legends: {},
        },
    },
};


new Chart(ctx, config);
```